# Drillthrough by clicking on a chart/table element in Power BI

Tags: powerbi

I'm wondering if it's possible at all to drillthrough data in another page by just clicking on a specific chart/table/matric column or element? Normally, I need to right-click on a given element and choose 'Drillthrough' > 'some details page..'. Can I do this just by clicking on an element? Example:

[image]

Let's say I have a pie chart as shown above. What I would like to do is left-click on a 'In Full Delivery' element and see (I could move to this detailed page manually) data filtered by this element in detailed page:

[image]

Is that possible? (i'm not talking about adding special button on my report which filters data based on a condition, just clicking on a chart/table etc. element)